# AdMob Interstitial stopped working

Tags: android, ios, react-native, admob, interstitial

The Interstitial ad was working properly and after two days of testing it stopped working. I have the error: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks`. This error is only for the Interstitial ad. I have AdMobBanner but it's working perfectly fine. For both I use the test ids from https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads. I have tried to create different app but it's the same. Also have tried with real ad but again not working. It's not working on both platform - iOS & Android. My AdMob account is not banned or showing any warning messages. I am using https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob with the following code:

```
AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910');
AdMobInterstitial.setTestDevices([AdMobInterstitial.simulatorId]);
AdMobInterstitial.requestAd().then(() => AdMobInterstitial.showAd());
```

As I said it was working for two days.

Comment: It is probably a NO_FILL message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How I can fix that?

Comment: if it is what I said, it means that the ad network does not have any ad to return. There is nothing to do, but wait.

Comment: I am already waiting day and a half. How much time should go before I see again a test ad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with the interstitial ad server that is causing this problem that appears to be cross-platform. It relates to a no ads fill issue, even with test ads. I’m on Android and experiencing the same problem. Like many others, I have flagged this up with Google and they’ve responded and appear to be working on it as we speak, we hope!

Stay tuned to this thread and hopefully we’ll get an update shortly: [Google AdMob Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!categories/google-admob-ads-sdk/android)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try,
if (AdMobInterstitial.isLoaded() || AdMobInterstitial.isLoading()) {
  AdMobInterstitial.showAd()
}
```

1. Add Above line add and check.
2. remove `AdMobInterstitial.setTestDevices([AdMobInterstitial.simulatorId]);` this line and check.

check both scenario.